# Observer in DS.Model for an attribute fires when even the attribute is just used in template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've written an array controller with pagination function.

When I switch to another pages for the first time, there's no problem.
But if I reviist the page I visited before, and observer for an attribute that is used is template is triggered.
(in this case, `published`)

When I remove `{{#unless published}}...{{/unless}}` from template, the observer isn't triggered anymore when I revisit the page where I've already visited.

I don't think I've done weird thing on my controllers....

(When pagination button is clicked, it simply changes controllers's `page`)
(I've written observer for `title` in model class to test whether this issue is limited to `published` property, and observer for `title` also behaves like observer for `published`. So this issue doesn't seem to limited to `published` property )

I'm using
Ember      : 1.7.1+pre.f095a455
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.9
Handlebars : 1.3.0 
jQuery     : 1.11.1 
and I tried beta and canary version of ember, but this issue remains same.

[image: might_be_bug]

Here is my Route

```
MuteAdmin.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params, transition, queryParams) {
    var search = params.search || '';
    var page = params.page || 1;


    return this.store.find(this.get('articleModelClassName'), {
      search: search,
      page: page
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    var will_paginate_meta = model.get("meta.will_paginate");

    controller.set('totalPages', will_paginate_meta.total_pages);
    controller.set('previousPage', will_paginate_meta.previous_page);
    controller.set('nextPage', will_paginate_meta.next_page);
  }
});
```

and here is my controller

```
MuteAdmin.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(MuteAdmin.Modelable, {
  queryParams: ['page', 'search'],
  page: 1,
  totalPages: null,
  pageChanged: function() {
    this.store.find(this.get('articleModelClassName'), {
      search: this.get('search'),
      page: this.get('page')
    }).then(function(model) {
      this.set('model', model);

      var will_paginate_meta = model.get("meta.will_paginate");
      this.set('totalPages', will_paginate_meta.total_pages);
      this.set('previousPage', will_paginate_meta.previous_page);
      this.set('nextPage', will_paginate_meta.next_page);
    }.bind(this));
  }.observes('page'),

  actions: {
    doSearch: function() {
      this.store.find(this.get('articleModelClassName'), {
        search: this.get('search'),
        page: 1
      }).then(function(model) {
        this.set('model', model);

        var will_paginate_meta = model.get("meta.will_paginate");
        this.set('totalPages', will_paginate_meta.total_pages);
        this.set('previousPage', will_paginate_meta.previous_page);
        this.set('nextPage', will_paginate_meta.next_page);
        this.set('page', will_paginate_meta.current_page);
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
});
```

and here is my template

```
{{#each controller}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{link-to title "edit" this}} {{#unless published}}<small class="text-muted">비공개</small>{{/unless}}</td>
      <td>{{author.name}}</td>
      <td>{{category.title}}</td>
      <td>시간 지정</td>
      <td>{{viewCount}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

and here is my model which has observers

```
MuteAdmin.Article = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  body: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category'),
  author: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  viewCount: DS.attr('number'),
  published: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: true }),
  publishScheduled: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
  publishScheduleTime: DS.attr('date'),

  publishedChanged: function() {
    if (this.get('published') == true) {
      this.set('publishScheduled', false);
    } 
    console.log('published changed! ' + this.toString());
  }.observes('published'), 
});
```

Comment: Is published always set?  If you add `{{published}}` to the template, what does it show up as?  Is it changing the second time you see it?

Comment: As you can see in model file, published has default value of true. and the list view only shows persisted articles.

Comment: so published value shows the persisted value always properly. so values does not change when I see those for the second time

Comment: Yes, but certain combinations of Ember/Ember-Data treated `defaultValue` differently, hence my curiosity of whether or not your value is always set in your json.  And since I can't find your exact version, I'm having a hard time replicating: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1040/edit.  This small one is working, so I'm curious of the difference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I know what it is.  Your making a call to the server for the records that already exist.  The results are merging into the pre-existing records in the store causing the model to invalidate and observer to fire.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1043/edit

Comment: Then model observer can't be used with server side pagination at all?

Comment: Since you really don't care about caching you can just unload the store for that type so it doesn't merge into preexisting records.  I'm on my phone so I can't really give a good example.  It's this.store.unload('type')

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: according to stefan penner. this will behavior will be changed someday to not firing observer if the fetch result and existing model in store are same.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2334#issuecomment-57425994

Comment: That'll be good, no point in firing an observer if the value is the same.  Thanks.